# Printing the month name extracted from a sheet in the next sheets particular row

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 input sheets and 10 corresponding output sheets. The column D in input sheet contains date in the `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` format. I am trying to write a code which will extract the month from the D column and paste this month name on every filled column stating from 3 in row 1 in respective output sheets.The following is my code, it shows error.

> Object doesn't support this property or method

...on this line:

```
Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Ra1 = MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2")))
```

How do I rectify this?

```
Sub RenamingOutputSheets1()

Dim Ra1 As Range
Dim lastCol4 As Integer
Dim wsarray1 As Sheets
Set wsarray1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

For Each sheetobject In wsarray
Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Activate
lastCol4 =ActiveSheet.Cells(2,ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Ra1 = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, lastCol4))
Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Ra1 =   MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2")))
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Untested: Based on your above comment (I haven't read the complete question), Change `Set Ra1 = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, lastCol4))` to `Set Ra1 = Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Range(Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Cells(1, 3), Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Cells(1, lastCol4))` and then change `Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Ra1 =   MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2")))` to `Ra1 =   MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2").Value))`

Answer (score 0):

```
dim w as long, lastCol4 as long, Ra1 as Range
for w = 2 to worksheets.count
    with worksheets(w)
        lastCol4 = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        set Ra1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, lastCol4))
        Ra1 = Format(worksheets(w - 1).Range("D2"), "mmmm")
    end with
next w
```

I'm not at all sure what you planned to do with `Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1)` when you were on the last worksheet.

Comment: The month will be picked from D column from say a sheet and the month name will be printed in the row 1 of the next sheet. That is the reason for using Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1)

Comment: Sure, but you are cycling through all of the worksheets. What are you going to do with worksheet+1 when you are on the last worksheet?

Comment: In the previous code I have defined the array for objectsheet which contains the sheets for the same. Also there are previously created sheets  after each of these sheets which I'm referring to as     Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1)